# Security and encryption of passwords for multiple login automation using Selenium in Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, password-protection, password-encryption

I am currently developing a web automation system that helps me know how mutch money I have on different web pages I use. The problem is that I made selenium read a file with all the passwords for each webpage. This is because i am opening one webdriver, loging in a page, getting the data i need and going to the next row of the passwords file. More clearly: it is a for loop that runs over each of the web pages (rows of the file) and for each web page there is a different user and password.

My question is the following: How can I mantain security over my passwords. Encrypting the file has to be a priority since its saved locally and if someone has local access to my computer all my passwords are leaked. Also inside of selenium, I supose thet whenever it reads a password from the file and uses it, it does it without beeing secure, so incercepting processes (I supose this is possible) could also leak passwords. Is there any way of avoiding this threads? I dont mind changing the thought process behind the application if there is no way of having it secure with this way of working.

PD: I still have to develop almost all the application so this part is not implemented. By the time i have to implement it I want to do it safely.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You can use a dedicated browser profile with stored credentials.

Comment: @pburgr uh, didnt think about that. I have a dedicated profile on chrome for these webs so this can be the best solution. Selenium has the hability to get the google account stored passwords and send these keys?

Comment: @Neruzz selenium does not need to store neither send any keys. Simply login to google manualy in specific browser profile and use the same browser profile for selenium.